# How to keep data in ActionFilterAttribute after redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on `ASP.NET MVC 4` application. I've created custom filter which purpose is to call page which display loader image. The filter looks like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            var useLoader = filterContext.RouteData.Values["ul"] as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(useLoader))
            {
                var view = new ViewResult()
                {
                    ViewName = "DisplayLoader"
                };

                view.ViewData.Model = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
                view.TempData["ul"] = "1";
                filterContext.Result = view;
            }
        }
```

In the `DisplayLoader` view I just do this:

```
@model string

<script type="text/javascript">window.location = '@Html.Raw(Model)';</script>
```

but the problem is that after the redirect the `useLoader` value is always `null`. Is there way to persist this data?

Comment: what is `useLoader `  ? And which data you want to persist ? where ? With your current code, It is going to do a non-stop  redirect loop.

Comment: @Shyju Well, I thought it's clear from the code but `useLoader` actually is the part where I want to get the persisted value from the redirect. As you can see I se in the `TempData` the key `[ul]` and in the code is one of the many ways I tried to check for this key after the redirect exactly to escape from infnite loop, but I was not able to set the `ul` key and get it back after the `window.location` redirect.